# Twilio support ticket creation does not work

Tags: twilio, sip

When I try to create a support ticket. There is an error message saying the ticket cannot be created every time.

I am trying to report problems with the SIP/2.0 implementation Twilio offers and I have contacted their sales phone number and not received a call back.